# Injecting Services into a Service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to inject public services like entityManager in the constructor of a service I created but I keep having this error :

**Too few arguments to function App\Services\BillingInterface::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/.../src/Controller/TestController.php on line 144 and exactly 1 expected.**

In my controllers, services are correctly injected in different methods but in the service I created it's not injected in the constructor.

I didn't change anything in the services.yaml as the documentation says autowire is automatic in Symfony 4.2

PS : I recently updated from Symfony 4.1 to 4.2 and I'm not sure but I think it worked before.

Maybe a library didn't updated correctly but I don't find any errors.

[Here are the informations for the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In7Rv.png)

Service code :

```
#/src/Services/BillingInterface

namespace App\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class BillingInterface {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

}
```

Controller code :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Services\BillingInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TestController extends AbstractController {

    public function teest(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $billing = new BillingInterface();
    }


}
```

And If I instantiate BillingInterface with `$entityManager` parameter of Controller, it works but I would like it injected directly in the `BillingInterface` class constructor.

And finally, here is what is written in Symfony's documentation :

```
// src/Service/MessageGenerator.php
// ...

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getHappyMessage()
    {
        $this->logger->info('About to find a happy message!');
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Link** : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

**Chapter** : Injecting Services/Config into a Service

So, I don't know what's wrong with my Service.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hint: the php new operator knows nothing about the Symfony container.

Comment: Okay but what about Symfony's documentation where it seems they achieve that ? Link at the end of my message.

Comment: Can you point out where in the docs the new operator is used?  In any event, @Flying's answer below will point you in the right direction.  Of course you should really should not have a class with a suffix of 'Interface'. But that is a different topic.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since your `BillingInterface` is a service - you need to use its instance that is provided by Symfony container instead of attempting to instantiate it by yourself. Your controller needs to inject this service in order to be able to use it:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Services\BillingInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var BillingInterface
     */
    private $billing;

    /**
     * @param BillingInterface $billing
     */
    public function __construct(BillingInterface $billing)
    {
        $this->billing = $billing;
    }

    public function teest(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        // Use $this->billing ... 
    }
}
```